# C++ functional: bind classes method through pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, functional-programming, std-function, stdbind

I tried to bind a classes method from another class which is storing the first one's pointer, but it always gives me different value.
What am I doing wrong?

If I pass class A by value (and of course modify class B to store by value) it's working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A(double a, double b) : a(a), b(b) {}
    double mul(void) {return a*b;}

private:
    double a;
    double b;
};

class B {
typedef std::function<double(void)> function;

public:
    B(A* ap) : ap(ap) {}

    function a_mul = bind(&A::mul, ap);

private:
    A* ap;
};

int main() {
  A* a = new A(2,3);
  B b(a);

  cout << b.a_mul() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: a_mul can't be initialized inline like that, so I presume this is not the exact code you're running. Aside from the a_mul initialization, it looks ok. So the problem must lie in something that's not being shown...

Comment: @dlf "a_mul can't be initialized inline like that" yes it can, welcome to C++11.

Comment: @n.m. Neat! But not Microsoft's (2012) C++11, apparently. :(

Comment: @mooattyi I just wanted to say that for a first question, this is a really good post. You provided an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that clearly demonstrates the problem. Keep it up!

Comment: @dlf 2012 is severely lacking in the 2011 department. Try 2013 or clang or gcc.

Comment: @n.m. Not really practical, I'm afraid. Hopefully SO can at least continue to educate me until I get to the point where I quit embarrassing myself by saying something's not possible when it's really just that my compiler won't do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a non-static data member initializer to initialize `a_mul`. The initial value depends on the value of `ap`. However, the definition of `ap` follows that of `a_mul`. This means that `a_mul` will be initialized **prior to** the initialization of `ap` in the constructor. At the time initilization occurs, `ap` has an indeterminate value, and thus your code has undefined behavior.

One way to fix this is changing the order of definition of the member variables:

```
class B {
typedef std::function<double(void)> function;

public:
    B(A* ap) : ap(ap) {}

    A* ap;
    function a_mul = bind(&A::mul, ap);
};
```

But a better fix would be reorder the data members, *and* initialize `a_mul` in the constructor's initializer list.

```
class B {

typedef std::function<double(void)> function;

private:
    A* ap;

public:
    B(A* ap) : ap(ap), a_mul(bind(&A::mul, ap)) {}

    function a_mul;
};
```

Comment: Thank You very much for the answer, that was the solution!